# Erasing an element of a string using an index with str.erase()?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I use the `erase()` method to erase part of a `std::string` "str" in the form of `str.erase(str[i])`?

When I run the below code, it outputs the string minus the first element only, and then some weird characters.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "Please input the desired string : \n";
    cin >> s;
    int sz = sizeof s;
    int x = sz / 2;
    if ((sizeof s)%2 != 0)
    {
        s.erase(s[x]);
    }
    else
    {
        s.erase(s[x-1], s[x]);
    }
    for (int j=1; j <= sz; j++)
    {
        cout << s[j];
    }    
}
```

Comment: To see how to use erase see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase

Comment: Sizeof does not do what you expect it to do

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are trying to erase, so please provide some examples of input you type in, and what output you expect to see for them.

Answer (score 0):

The [`std::string::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) method has several overloads:

```
basic_string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );
iterator erase( iterator position );
iterator erase( const_iterator position );
iterator erase( iterator first, iterator last );
iterator erase( const_iterator first, const_iterator last );
```

`s.erase(s[x])` calls the first overload, treating `s[x]` as the `index` (because a `char` is implicitly convertible to `std::string::size_type`).

First, `s[x]` is not an valid index (`x` alone is, though), so this is **undefined behavior**.

Second, you are not explicitly specifying a value for the `count` parameter, so the default value of [`npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) is used, which tells `erase()` to remove *all* characters including *and after* the specified `index`, which is probably not what you want (or is it? Do you want to remove only the 1 `char` at the `index`, or *all* `char`s following the `index`?).

`s.erase(s[x-1], s[x])` also calls the first overload (implicitly converting the 2 `char`s to `size_type`).  Again, the `char`s you are passing in are not not valid indexes or counts, so this is also **undefined behavior**.

There are other problems in your code, as well.

`sizeof s` returns the byte size of `s` (ie, the size of the `std::string` class itself), not the length of the character data that `s` contains.  Those characters are stored elsewhere in memory (unless you input a small string, and your STL's implementation of `std::string` employs [Small String Optimization](https://blogs.msmvps.com/gdicanio/2016/11/17/the-small-string-optimization/)). Use `s.length()` or `s.size()` to get the length of the character data.

You are seeing unexpected output because `std::string` indexes are 0-based, not 1-based.  Your `for` loop skips the 1st character in `s`, and goes past the end of `s` into surrounding memory, which is also **undefined behavior**.  More importantly, you are modifying the length of `s` when you call `s.erase()`, but you are not updating your `sz` variable to reflect that new length, so your `for` loop potentially goes WAY past the end of `s`.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    string s;

    cout << "Please input the desired string : \n";
    cin >> s;

    size_t sz = s.length();
    size_t x = sz / 2;

    if ((sz % 2) != 0)
    {
        s.erase(x, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        s.erase(x-1, 2); // or (x-1, 1)? What do you want to erase exactly?
    }

    sz = s.length();

    for (int j = 0; j < sz; ++j)
    {
        cout << s[j];
    }    

    return 0;
}
```